# Given a continuous $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is there a cont $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that restriction of $g$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is f?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> Given a continuous $f : \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$ there is a cont $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that restriction of $g$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ is f

The example I could come up  with is $$f:\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q} ;f = \frac{1}{x-c}$$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q}$.

I think this function $f$ is continuous in it's domain  but it doesnot have a cont. extension to $\mathbb{R}$.

Here's another function I was thinking of:

Let $$f(x)=\frac{1}{q}; x=\frac{p}{q},gcd(p,q)=1$$

This is something similar to the thomae's function .So is this function continuous if we restrict the domain?Also I dont think intuitively that it will have a continuous extension to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Your example is correct.

Comment: No, it doesn't work because the range isn't a subset of $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: You might want to frame the question as a question rather than as as assertion to be proved.

Comment: The Thomae-like function is not continuous on the rationals anywhere. Given $f(x)=1/q,$ there are values near $x$ where $f(y)$ is arbitrarily close to $0.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is wrong, because $f(q)$ is not rational when $q$ is rational.

But you are right to seek a simple function which has a discontinuity at an irrational value.

You can show, surprisingly, that$$f(q)=\begin{cases}1&q^2<2\\0&q^2>2\end{cases}$$ is continuous as a function $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q.$

Functions similar to yours, but which return rationals, are like:

$$f(q)=\frac1{q^2-2}$$

Comment: A nice example.Also can you go through the function I just thought of.

Comment: @ThirstForMaths Pick a value for $c$ and then calculate a few values.  You'll find that they are not rational.

Comment: @badjohn I am talking about the next example that I gave

Comment: @ThirstForMaths Pick a value, e.g. $1$ which maps to $1$.  Now you can pick other rationals as close as you like to $1$ which map to very different values e.g. $\frac{1000...001}{1000...000}$ maps to $\frac{1}{1000...000}$.

Comment: I am sorry if it sounds stupid but shouldn't it be like showing that for every $\epsilon > 0$  there exists a $\delta >0$ and how does it intuitively contradict that fact.

Comment: Maybe ask a separate question on this so it is easier to give a longer explanation.